# Event not visible on Etherscan transaction list

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, ether

I have a BuyToken event when user send ether to smart contract they will receive tokens based on ether amount. For ex: 1 ETH = 1000 Token.

```
/// This notifies clients about the Buy Token
event BuyToken(address user, uint256 eth, uint256 token);
```

There is my buy() function

```
 /**
*  function for Buy Token
*/

function buy() payable public returns (uint amount){
      require(msg.value > 0);

      amount = ((msg.value.mul(TokenPerETHBuy)).mul( 10 ** uint256(decimals))).div(1 ether);
      balanceOf[this] -= amount;                        // adds the amount to owner's 
      balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount; 
      emit BuyToken(msg.sender,msg.value,amount);
      return amount;
}
```

It works well when user send ether user will receive tokens.

But this transaction event is not visible on Etherscan.io

For ex:
[Ropsten link](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x88ceb0dca6d9ad1007e534712ae4e67565d9e1a56244cf32a463dc9dd5f7ef4f)

I send 0.2 ether I receive 200 tokens. I can see ether transaction. But received tokens transaction not visible on "**ERrc20 Token Txns**" tab.

Pelase can you help ??

Comment: This? https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x88ceb0dca6d9ad1007e534712ae4e67565d9e1a56244cf32a463dc9dd5f7ef4f#eventlog

Comment: Yeah There is BuyToken even but on Erc20Token txns tab you can not see receveid token amount on that user address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to emit the Transfer event for Etherscan to see it as a token transfer . Most people handle this by logging 0x0 as the `from` address.

Comment: Should I change BuyToken -> Transfer event ?

Comment: You can emit both if you want, and you have to if you want to query for BuyToken events later.

Comment: emit BuyToken(msg.sender,msg.value,amount);
emit Transfer(msg.sender,this ,amount);